# SQL Query logic with zend framework 

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

So, my situation in logics is kind'a bad, and my math is not that good,
so i need your help "building" a query to fetch information from 3 different tables by join query.
my structure is like this:

- Users table : with primary key "ID"
- Campaigns table : with primary key "ID"
- User_Campaign table : with user_id, and campaign_id rows.

I want to pull all the campaigns that doesn't exist in user_campaign table with the user id X.

my query is for zend framework.
I will appreciate any kind of help, so thanx, and good evening from israel!

my current query:

```
$q = $this->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from(array('c' => 'campaigns'))
                ->join(array('uc'=> 'user_campaign'), 'uc.campaign_id != c.id AND uc.user_id != 1', array('campaign_id', 'user_id'));
```

Comment: at least make some kind of effort.

Comment: i really really tried, more than hour and a half, my logic sense is really suck, i swear!

Comment: Can you post what you've done? Even if it's terrible, it will motivate people to help you, instead of doing your job for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query out, using a left join, and adding a WHERE on the joined table for a valid id being null, will return results that don't exist on the right side of the join

```
public function check_access($campaign_id, $user_id) {
    $q = $this->select()
        ->from(array('c' => 'campaigns'))
        ->joinRight(array('uc'=> 'user_campaign'), 'uc.campaign_id = c.id', array('campaign_id', 'user_id'));
        ->where('uc.user_id != ?', $user_id)
        ->where('campaign_id = ?', $campaign_id);

    // User has an entry, return false
    if($this->fetchRow($select))
        return false;

    // User wasn't found, create an entry, and return true
    $this->insert('users_campaigns', array(
        'user_id'       => $user_id,
        'campaign_id'   => $campaign_id
    ));

    return true;
}
```

Comment: still dont work :(
maybe i didnt explained my self as well, so:
everytime user see's a campaign, i dont want him to see him again...
(hope this will help)

Comment: The edit should get you closer to your ultimate goal, that's the most I can provide for you under the circumstances, and I certainly hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing the `ON` from the `JOIN` correctly. You want the `uc.campaign_id = c.id` not `!=`

Answer (score 1):

Bryan! thanx a lot, finally i managed to do it with a lot help from the query you did before, and the final query i wrote is this:

```
$q = $this->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array('c' => 'campaigns'))
            ->joinLeft(array('uc' => 'user_campaign'), "uc.campaign_id = c.id AND uc.user_id = '$id'")
            ->where('uc.campaign_id IS NULL');
```

thank you again guys!
you are awesome!